# Celery starts the scheduler more often than specified in the settings

Tags: django, celery, scheduled-tasks

Tell me in what there can be a problem with Celery worker? When I run it, it starts executing the task more often than once a second, although it takes an interval of several minutes.

- Running the bit: "celery market_capitalizations beat -l info --scheduler django_celery_beat.schedulers: DatabaseScheduler"
- Launch of a vorker: "celery -A market_capitalizations worker -l info -S django"
   
  Maybe I'm not starting the service correctly?

Settings:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'exchange_rates',
        'django_celery_beat',
        'django_celery_results',
        ]
    TIME_ZONE = 'Europe / Saratov'
    USE_I18N = True
    USE_L10N = True
    USE_TZ = True

    CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis: // localhost: 6379'
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis: // localhost: 6379'
    CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application / json']
    CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
    CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
    CELERY_TIMEZONE = TIME_ZONE
    CELERY_ENABLE_UTC = False
    CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = 'django_celery_beat.schedulers: DatabaseScheduler'
```

[running services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6b2ma.png)

When the task is started, a request is not sent.
[admin panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9stZ.png)
Tell me, please, how to make a celery pick up task time from a web page and run the task with it?

I tried to run the task through the code, but it still runs more often than in a second.

```
from celery.schedules import crontab
    app.conf.beat_schedule = {
        'add-every-5-seconds': {
            'task': 'save_exchange_rates_task',
            'schedule': 600.0,
            # 'args': (16, 16)
        },
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the similiar issue when using django-celery-beat. But when I turn off USE_TZ(USE_TZ = False), the issue was gone.
But I need set USE_TZ to False to let my app TZ not aware the time zone.
If you have any solution, can you share it? Thansk.
My dev environment:
Python 3.7 + Django 2.0 + Celery 4.2 + Django-celery-beat 1.4
BTW,
Now I am using configuration schedule in settings and it is working well
I am still finding the solution to use django-celery-beat to use the db to manager the tasks.

```
CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'audit-db-every-10-minutes': {
        'task': 'myapp.tasks.db_audit',
        'schedule': 600.0, # 10 minutes
        'args': ()
    },
}
```